# The difference between Z boson couplings for quarks and antiquarks

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction

I am trying to work out the difference between Z boson couplings for quarks and antiquarks.  I know that for quarks the Z has the following couplings:

$Z_u^- = \frac{1}{\cos \theta_w}(0.5 - 2.0\sin^2\theta_w / 3.0)$
$Z_u^+ = \frac{1}{\cos \theta_w}(2.0\sin^2\theta_w / 3.0)$
$Z_d^- = \frac{1}{\cos \theta_w}(-0.5 + 1.0\sin^2\theta_w / 3.0)$
$Z_d^+ = \frac{1}{\cos \theta_w}(1.0\sin^2\theta_w / 3.0)$

Where $\theta_w$ is the weak mixing angle and the + and - refer to positive and negative helicity resp.
Could someone confirm for me how this changes for the case of a Z couplings to an antiquark - I have an idea but I dont think it is correct.
Cheers,
Jack

Comment: The vertex is z quark antiquark. There are not separate z quark quark and z antiquark antiquark couplings. Such couplings would break e.g. charge conservation.

Comment: @innisfree You could expand this into a short answer so that it does not remain omments may disappear after all.

Comment: Nice one cheers

Comment: Ok I understand that @innisfree but then if we look at the case of a quark (or antiquark) radiating off a Z boson surely it cant change to an antiquark (or quark) because that too would violate charge conservation?

Comment: Also if a Z decays to a quark antiquark pair then the q qbar must have different helicities to conserve helicity overall, and then which of the couplings in my original question do we use?